# beamer style text box

Tags: boxes

If you're using beamer you can do some nice text boxes using:

```
\begin{block}{block title}content of block\end{block}
```

Which gives a text box something like this (the box with the header Esimerkki):

[image]

How can I do the same thing in a regular latex document (I really like the look of the beamer text boxes and would like as close to this as possible).

Minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
I wish I were inside of a really super cool text box so all the word would stop and look at me and say wow that text is pretty.  But alas I am just ordinary \LaTeX{} text.  I am sad.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package. A little example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black,title=A nice heading]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package can also be an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
linecolor=green!40!black,outerlinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},%
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitlerulecolor=green!40!black,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40!black,
backgroundcolor=green!5,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
roundcorner=5pt
}
\newmdenv[style=mystyle]{exa}
\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {\begin{exa}[frametitle=#1]}
  {\end{exa}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{The Title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I was looking for.  I'll mark it as correct as soon as the time limit expires.

Comment: Using the mdframed package: how can we add "example chapter's number and a counting number : and then "The title"?

Comment: @giannis please open a fresh new question.

Comment: **Note:** for document-wide settings with `tcolorbox`, use e.g. `\tcbset{colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black}` in your preamble. Styling is not applied to nested boxes. See [the docs](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

For the record, there is also the [bclogo package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bclogo). Can use PsTricks or Tikz as graphics engine. It has nice features, but unfortunatly, documentation is in french only. See code example and ouput below. (sorry for the poor colors choice, I am not good at that!)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\presetkeys{bclogo}{
ombre=true,
epBord=3,
couleur = blue!15!white,
couleurBord = red,
arrondi = 0.2,
logo=\bctrombone
}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}{The title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```