# \fbox around type area

Tags: minipage

I'm trying to put a border around multiple lines. Here's a MWE with what I've achieved so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
text text text

\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth - 2\fboxsep}
    text in box
  \end{minipage}
}

more text
\end{document}
```

This results in something like this:

```
  text text text
  +-------------+
  | text in box |
  +-------------+
  more text
```

I would like the sideways borders to be around the type area:

```
  text text text
+-----------------+
| text in box     |
+-----------------+
  more text
```

But how can I do this?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74126/beamer-style-text-box

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The idea is to typeset a minipage and frame it; however we have to push it a bit leftwards and avoid overfull boxes; here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par\kern#2
 }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{fminipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{fminipage}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You can also call it like

```
\begin{fminipage}{\textwidth}[1ex]
```

with any dimension you like, for stating the separation from the lines above and below (default is `\fboxsep`).

[image]

Comment: I noticed that if the text exactly fills one page, then this kicks the text and surrounding box onto a second page (leaving the first page blank).

Comment: @JoeCorneli Yes, of course. In that case the box is too large and TeX does its best.

Comment: This is not working for me; it may be to do with `xparse`, which is not on my version of MiKTeX 2.9. Is it something to do with LaTeX3 vs LaTeX2e, which I am using?

Comment: @user2868156 Can you give some more information?

Comment: Yes! I get the error `File xparse.sty not found.` when compiling. I also tried downloading `xparse.sty` itself and the `l3packages.zip` files, but to no avail. Is MiKTeX just not recognizing it?

Comment: @user2868156 What version of MiKTeX are you running?

Comment: It is version 2.9.4503 as far as I can tell

Comment: @user2868156 You should use the MiKTeX package manager for installing packages you don't have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15989/discussion-between-user2868156-and-egreg).

Answer (score 6):

You can use a negative space to reset the indentation

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
text text text

\hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxrule-\fboxsep\relax}\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\widthof{text in box}}
    text in box
  \end{minipage}%
}

more text
\end{document}
```

Also you need to remove the spurious space with `%` after `\fbox`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly then you want to `\hskip/\hspace*` left by `2\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
text text text

\hspace*{\dimexpr-2\fboxsep-\fboxrule} \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth - 2\fboxsep}
   text in box
  \end{minipage}
  }

  more text
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
text text text

\hspace*{-2.5mm}%
\fbox{%
  \hspace*{2.5mm}\hspace*{-1\fboxsep}%
  \parbox{\textwidth + 5mm - 2\fboxsep}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth - 2\fboxsep}
    text in box
  \end{minipage}
  }%
}

more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text 
\end{document}
```

[image]