# How to split the frame horizontally?

Tags: enumerate, rules, framed, border

I need the following format for one my report.
[image]

### How to achieve this?

So far, I have tried using 
  `framed` environment to get the borders and adjusted the `rule` command to split the frame environment vertically. Now horizontally also I need to split which I am not able to achieve.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in \topmargin 0in \textheight 9.2in  \textwidth 6.5in
\usepackage{enumitem, lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\newlength{\framedline}
\setlength{\framedline}{\textwidth plus 18pt}
\let\oldrule\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[2]{
   \hspace*{-36.7pt}\oldrule{\framedline}{0.4pt}\newline
}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}\bfseries 
PROGRESS REPORT OF THE PROJECT \\
YEAR: 2015-2017(2 years)
    \end{center}
\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}\rule\\
\item \begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}\rule
\lipsum[1-20]
%
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed} 


\end{document}
```

### Current Output:

[image]

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88624/28557

Answer (score 3):

It is not quite clear what you really want to achieve. But with tcolorbox you can draw horizontal lines without problems

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}\bfseries
PROGRESS REPORT OF THE PROJECT \\
YEAR: 2015-2017(2 years)
    \end{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw,colframe=black,
                  opacityback=0,breakable,
                  sharp corners,
                  segmentation style={solid,thick}]
\begin{enumerate}
\item abc

\tcbline

\item abc
\item abc \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\tcbline

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]