# Pgfplots height in subfigure not consistent to adjacent includegraphics

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, vertical-alignment, subcaption, external-files

I want to place 3 pictures next to each other using [`subcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=de). The two right pictures are external graphics files that I include using `\includegraphics`. The left one is supposed to be a [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=de) chart. Naturally, I want them  and the captions to align vertically. To achieve set I use a common height for all three pictures which is defined in `\figheight`. As a dry run, everything seems to work with *example-image-a*, etc:

[image]

However, when I replace the left figure by a pgfplot and specify its exact `height` to the height of the external figures right next, the result is somehow curious:

[image]

Why is the height not exactly the value of `\figheight`? Is there a difference between the height of the axis environment and the height of the tikzpicture? From the manual:

> If scale only axis=false (the default), pgfplots will try to produce the desired width including labels, titles and ticks.

I guess the same holds for the height?! How can I fix this for a proper alignment of the pictures as well as the subcaptions?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newlength{\figheight}
\setlength{\figheight}{5cm}

\begin{document}

Works:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.65\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Test1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Test2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Test3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall caption}
\end{figure}

Weird size and resulting caption position:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.65\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        height=\figheight,
      ]
        \addplot+ {x};
        \addlegendentry{$f(x)=x$}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Test2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Test3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `axis` environment will take into account, for the `height`, also the minimum size of the title and of the `xlabel`. See:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% modified from @egreg idea https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88624/38080
\usepackage{xparse}
\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{O{c} O{} O{c} m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#5\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
     \begin{minipage}[#1][#2][#3]{#4}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#4]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par\kern#5
 }

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newlength{\figheight}
\setlength{\figheight}{5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.65\linewidth}
    \centering
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \begin{fminipage}[t][\figheight][t]{\linewidth}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        height=\figheight,
        width=\linewidth,
        xlabel=$x$,
        title = title,
      ]
        \addplot+ {x};
        \addlegendentry{$f(x)=x$}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{fminipage}
    \caption{Test1 \the\linewidth \the\figheight}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Test2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Test3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which gives (notice I added a ["no size" frame around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88616/fbox-around-type-area)):

[image: perfectly aligned things...]

I do not know how to remove these sizes from the graph. Something on the line of

```
\begin{axis}[
        height=\figheight+\baselineskip,
        width=\linewidth,
        xlabel = \empty,
        title = \empty,
      ]
```

gives a better appearance:

[image: try one]

but I feel this is a bit of an hack...

The best I can suggest is to add the external (zero size) frame and remove the graph one, like:

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{fminipage}[t][\figheight][t]{\linewidth}%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        height=\figheight+\baselineskip,
        width=\linewidth,
        xlabel = \empty,
        title = \empty,
        axis x line = center, 
        axis y line = center,
        ]
        \addplot+ {x};
        \addlegendentry{$f(x)=x$}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{fminipage}
```

which gives:

[image: second try]

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly aligned but fairly close:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newlength{\figheight}
\setlength{\figheight}{5cm}

\begin{document}

Works:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.65\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Test1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Test2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Test3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall caption}
\end{figure}

Weird size and resulting caption position:

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.65\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
 %       width=\linewidth,
        height=\figheight-\baselineskip, % changed
        scale only axis                  % added
      ]
        \addplot+ {x};
        \addlegendentry{$f(x)=x$}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Test2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\linewidth,height=\figheight]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Test3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to align the *bounding box* of the (whole) `axis` environment (and not only the "box" of the `axis` environment) you have to tweek the `height` a little bit. The [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=291) states in section 4.10.1 at the `height` key:

> [...]
>   Please note that pgfplots only estimates the size needed for axis and
>   tick labels. The estimate assumes a fixed amount of space for anything
>   which is outside of the axis box. This has the effect that the final
>   images may be slightly larger or slightly smaller than the prescribed
>   dimensions. However, the fixed amount is always the same; it is set to
>   45pt.
>   [...]

As Rmano already stated in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377147) this is approximately the additional size of the

- ticklabels,
- axis labels, and
- title.

Thus, if some of them are missing, we have to "compensate" for that.

Please find attached some code how I would do it together with a lot of comments.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use layers to show the bounding boxes of the `axis' environments
        set layers={
            background,
            main,
        },
    }
    \newlength{\figheight}
    \setlength{\figheight}{5cm}
\begin{document}
    % by default the `width' and `height' are reduced by 45pt which is used
    % for ticklabels, axis labels and the title
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\figheight,
            height=\figheight,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            title=title,
            name=p,
        ]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill [yellow!10] (p.outer south west)
                rectangle (p.outer north east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \draw [red] (p.outer south east)
            -- +(0,\figheight) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw [red] (p.outer south east)
            -- +(-\figheight,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \includegraphics[angle=90,height=\figheight]{example-image-a}
    %
    % so if no title and y label are given and we want to align the bounding
    % box of the whole `axis' environment (not only the box of the `axis'
    % environment) with the bounding box of the graphics, we have to enlarge
    % the `height' (manually) to fit to the desired `height'.
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\figheight,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            height=\figheight + 30pt,
%            % -------------------------
%            % equivalently we have to reduce the `height' if `scale only axis'
%            % is given
%            scale only axis,
%            height=\figheight - 15pt,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            name=q,
        ]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill [yellow!10] (q.outer south west)
                rectangle (q.outer north east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \draw [red] (q.outer south west)
            -- +(0,\figheight) circle (1.5pt);
        \fill [green] (q.outer north west) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]