# Create Beamer-Theorem like boxes

Tags: beamer, mdframed, framed, tcolorbox

I would like to create frames / boxes for equations or text like in the Beamer class: [image]

outisde of the beamer documentclass, for example in the `article` class. Is there any package or trick to do this?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package.  Does that look like what you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) has also a `beamer` skin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\colorlet{xlightblue}{blue!5}

\newtcolorbox{beamerlikethm}[1]{
  title=#1,
  beamer,
  colback=xlightblue,
  colframe=blue!30,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  left=1mm,
  right=1mm,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=1mm,
  middle=1mm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{beamerlikethm}{Theorem (Pythagoras)}
\[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]
\end{beamerlikethm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As Gonzalo suggested, could happen that your box necessitate of being split on different pages. The library `breakable` of the package deal with this problem.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{xlightblue}{blue!5}

\newtcolorbox{beamerlikethm}[1]{
  title=#1,
  beamer, 
  colback=xlightblue,
  colframe=blue!30,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  left=1mm,
  right=1mm,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=1mm,
  middle=1mm,
  breakable,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{beamerlikethm}{Theorem (Pythagoras)}
\[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]
\end{beamerlikethm}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{beamerlikethm}{Something}
\lipsum[5]
\end{beamerlikethm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you might want to add the `breakable` option so the box admits page breaks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: that's absolutely right. I'll add a reference on this.

Comment: Just some hints for adjusting the vertical spacing of the formula in the example: the additional loading of the `amsmath` package corrects the spacing before the equation. Alternatively, the `tcolorbox` library `theorems` could be used (which loads `amsmath`). For multiline formulas, the library has special support for the spacing at the begin of the box, e.g. see the option 'ams nodisplayskip'. :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: thank you very much for the suggestion. I will modify the answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 6):

Another approach with the »[tcolorbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)« package and its `theorems` library.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{%
  breakable,
  colback=blue!10,
  colframe=blue!25,
  fonttitle=\bfseries
}{cor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{corollary}{Title}{dummy}
    \[
      x+y=y+x
    \]
  \end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you might want to add the `breakable` option so the box admits page breaks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You forgot to mention that the `breakable` option needs the `breakable` library. Since it was not asked here for boxes which allow page breaks, there was no necessity to add it. But as you mention that now, the OP is aware of it.

Comment: Right, I didn't mention the library since I always load `tcolorbox` using `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`, so I don't have to worry about loading the libraries explicitly.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: That is a good option.

Answer (score 5):

[`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package might be helpful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!40!black,title=Theorem (Pythagoras)]
\[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The similar question was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74126/beamer-style-text-box).

Comment: Perhaps you might want to add the `breakable` option so the box admits page breaks.